# TYPO3 7.6 tx_news and shorturl with realurl

Tags: typo3, realurl, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

my news work fine with realurl and tx_news:

`www.domain.de/newslist/news-title-long-name-here/`

but how can i build with realurl a secound short-URL:

`www.mydomain.com/newslist/?test=1234`

thanks for helping

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a second short-url". Do you want to keep the realUrl mapping for the title and have an additional Short url that links to the same? Or do you want to disable the real Url mapping?

Comment: Can you please describe the URL you want in news ?

Comment: i need a shortner-url.
twitter, google, facebook use a shortner-url.
can i build this with realurl / TYPO3 ?

Comment: On a sidenote: make sure to set the canonical url for the news item to avoid duplicate content. I built an extension that does this (for tx_news) but it only takes absolute URLs as of now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible out of the box but would be really easy with a custom small extension